# Waiting for host FOREVER after .NET Framework upgrade

Tags: asp.net, .net, host, .net-framework-version

We just migrated our app from .NET Framework from 3.5 to 4.7 and IIS CLR to 4.0, and now we are getting issues where when opening the app, it says "Waiting for [host]" forever. We tested it on our development test server and it works perfectly. Our client test server is the one getting this issue. Any solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: we need more info... do have any logs at least?

Comment: No errors on the event logs. It just stuck on "Waiting response from host". I compared the IIS app pool setting and they are almost identical except for the urls. Also the code are exactly the same, except for connectionString.

Comment: try wireshark and see which host is not responding and check the code for timeouts